# How to limit packets per unit time on a particular interface (for vms)

Tags: iptables, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, packet

I am using kvm and virtuozzo virtualization on my servers and each having 10 vms.
I have to restrict DDOS attack from my VMS (i.e prevent VM from doing DDOS attack), I search on net and found that I can restrict number of packets using iptables hashlimit.
I tried some rules on my server and it is not working.

For eg vm1 having ip 10.1.3.29 is doing dodos attack I applied following rule.

```
iptables -I FORWARD -o viifv1052 -s 10.1.3.29 -m hashlimit --hashlimit-name stopddos --hashlimit-mode srcip --hashlimit-above 5/sec --hashlimit-burst 2 --hashlimit-htable-expire 30000 -j DROP
```

I also tried with -i :

```
iptables -I FORWARD -i viifv1052 -s 10.1.3.29 -m hashlimit --hashlimit-name ICMPTEST --hashlimit-mode srcip --hashlimit-above 5/sec --hashlimit-burst 2 --hashlimit-htable-expire 30000 -j DROP
```

Then I tried ebtables but no effect:

```
ebtables -I FORWARD -o viifv1052 --ip-source 10.1.3.29 --protocol ipv4 --limit 5/sec-j ACCEPT
ebtables -I FORWARD -o viifv1052 --ip-source 10.1.3.29 --protocol ipv4 -j DROP
```

Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Comment: You should give your complete network configuration, to help know if the firewall commands you gave actually make sense or not.